# Finding questions that have been asked before

Tags: discussion

Recently I seem to be asking more questions that have already been asked and answered, and I don't know if it is due to my inability to do searches, or there is something "off" with SO's own search process.

This question:

[What is TSQL TinyInt in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309155/what-is-tsql-tinyint-in-c)

was marked as a duplicate of:

[How can you convert "tinyint" of t-sql to integer in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922094/how-can-you-convert-tinyint-of-t-sql-to-integer-in-c)

Due to the simplicity of the question, I felt that it must have been asked before, but several search attempts using the search box didn't bring it up, and the "Questions that may already have your answer" didn't bring it up either.  Within a minute of the question being posted a user marked it as a dupe and provided the previously asked question.  Which had the correct information in it.

So, am I a clueless or sloppy searcher, or does SO's own search process need some tweaking?

Comment: I can almost never find what I need through SO's search box. I use Google and add the search term "stackoverflow."

Comment: the search on the top of the page does not seem to be as powerful as the search running for the question title if you are trying to create a question.

Comment: What galdre said except I don't usually include "stackoverflow" but the tag instead (ex. how do I foo this bar [android]). Also, being a dupe isn't always bad. If it includes different search terms than the target then it can be a great signpost for others using different search terms.

Comment: @galdre try the [stack exchange search page](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=) - its google behind it, searches all the stack exchange sites (not just SO... so if the question is on P.SE, or CS.SE, or SU, or... this will find it)

Comment: I'll bet many of the other moderators do what I do: when I notice a question that's duplicated frequently, I save a bookmark to it. Then I can easily find it again to mark new duplicates.

Comment: I'm not sure why your searches didn't find it. I searched for `[c#] tinyint`, sorted by votes, and that question was #5 in the results. The first item in the list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes/968734#968734, would also have been a good candidate for the duplicate.

Comment: you don't need to do an exhaustive search before asking a question (it might make it too localized). If the obvious search hadn't return satisfactory results then a new question (even if it is later marked as a duplicate) may be useful (to you and future visitors that use similar keywords to describe the problem).

Comment: @galdre I nearly always find what I need using the on-site [**SEARCH BOX**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: In addition to what @galdre commented, the proper Google search syntax for searching SO specifically would be: [stackoverflow.com: c# tinyint](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=stackoverflow.com:+c%23+tinyint#safe=off&q=stackoverflow.com:+c%23+tinyint). Take a look at their [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en-GB) for more info.

Comment: I frequently struggle using the search box and have found that it pretty much requires me to use the [tag] search syntax with very few keywords - and even then it's hit or miss. There have been times where I KNOW the question has been asked before and that I participated in the discussion, but to find it I had to dig through my personal profile activity as the search was of no help.

Comment: @Barmer, I believe you as to finding the right question, but I was using this Meta question to bring up the general case of not finding an answer or not finding possible dupes before actually answering the question.