# Is the "Questions that may already have your answer" search available elsewhere?

Tags: feature-request, search

I frequently use "Ask Question" as a SO search engine, as the "Questions that may already have your answer" suggestions often provide exactly the question I'm after. Is there a way of using this search without going via "Ask Question"?

I realise there are [similar questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273253/finding-questions-that-have-been-asked-before) out and about, but have found none that ask exactly what I'm asking. Furthermore, the suggestion of googling with "stackoverflow" as an additional search term usually don't yield as relevant results.

Comment: @JID this too does not yield as relevant results in most cases (or at least it hasn't for me).

Comment: I can't find it now, but it is a known issue that the search when asking is different to the regular search. Note that you can use `site:stackoverflow.com` to limit Google results, rather than just adding `stackoverflow` to the query.

Comment: Yeah actually i just tried it now, it does seem to yield far less relevant results.

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268318/3001761 - the difference is in searching the question *body* (regular search) vs. *title* (search-when-asking).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the "site:" suggestion, although I'm already aware of it. That too falls short of the suggestions from "Ask Question".

Comment: @jonrsharpe Haha, bummer that my question involving exploiting the "duplicate detector" turned out to be more or less a duplicate itself.

Comment: You can use a search query like `title:"your search phrase"`, still not very good though..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems to me that you're already using the proper tool for the job.

You get great "search" results because they are generated from the title of your question, the body of your question (even if it's incomplete) and the tags.

Any dedicated "search page" of this form would be indistinguishable from the "Ask Question" page, save for the lack of the "Submit Question" button … which you may then wish to press if the search turns up nothing of interest.